# In MacVim, why can't I goto a file with the gf command when having "filetype plugin indent on"?

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using MacVim Version 8.2.3455 (172)

I have a ruby file **vim_test.rb** with one line of code.

```
require 'vim_test/core'
```

The **vim_test/core.rb** file exists and has a single comment.

I do the following:

1. I navigate to the directory containing the **vim_test.rb** file and start MacVim with
   **mvim vim_test.rb**
2. I run the `:set suffixesadd+=.rb` command.
3. I put my cursor on the file specified by the require directive (**vim_test/core**) and press **gf**.

I get this error **E345: Can't find file "vim_test/core.rb" in path**.

To fix this, I have to comment out the following line in my **.vimrc**, save it and restart MacVim:

```
" filetype plugin indent on
```

Now when I follow the exact same steps as before, I can jump to the **vim_test/core.rb** file.

Is there any way I can have `filetype plugin indent on` in my .vimrc and also use **gf** to goto a file specified by the require directive?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help gf` works by searching for the filename under the cursor in the directories listed in the `:help 'path'`.

By default, the value of `path` is `.,/usr/include,,`, which means that Vim is going to search in:

- the directory of the current file, that's the `.`,
- `/usr/include`, which is of no use to you,
- the working directory, that's the `,,`.

Which works perfectly well with your sample.

Now, `filetype plugin indent on` tells Vim to enable filetype detection, filetype plugins, and filetype-specific indenting. The problem, here, is that the Ruby filetype plugin tries hard to locate all the places on your system that might hide Ruby libs and then sets the `path` option to that list. For example, this is what I get on my machine (YMMV):

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0,/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18,/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/universal-darwin18,/Library/Ruby/Site,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18
```

This is probably useful but it lacks the `.` that allows searching in the directory of the current file and the `,,` that allows searching in the working directory.

In fact, the function that returns the value to be used for `path` does something very weird: if the current global value of `path` *isn't* the default value, it appends the list of directories above but, if the global value *is* the default value, it simply returns the list above. I can't quite wrap my head around that reasoning.

Moreover, the same ftplugin maps `gf` to some clever function that makes it even more complicated and unintuitive.

The only workaround I can see is to change your global `path` in your `vimrc` in such a way that the Ruby ftplugin *appends* the list above to the existing `path` value instead of *overriding* it with that list.

The following snippet:

```
set path+=,,
```

gets me the following `path` in a Ruby buffer:

```
.,/usr/include/,,,,,/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0,/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18,/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/universal-darwin18,/Library/Ruby/Site,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin18,/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18
```

which makes `gf` work as expected.

But such a hack shouldn't be needed in the first place. I think an issue is in order.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the answer.